# Taming the Mattock in Mass Effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3

I was wondering if anyone is using the Mattock in Mass Effect 3 and if so, how did you tackle the floatyness of it. The Mattock in Mass Effect 2 was well balanced and had very little muzzle climb or sway if you paced your shots but I am finding that the Mass Effect 3 version is much more unwieldy.

Did you add weapon mods to the rifle, just deal with it and account for it when shooting, or transition to a different gun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not fully automatic, so if you don't spam fire it you can compensate between trigger pulls.  It also does a ton of damage so if you're hitting your targets you shouldn't need to unload it.  Also, Adrenaline Rush is your friend here.

(You can probably mod it to make life easier, of course, but I've not really considered it enough of a problem to put much effort into mine.)

Comment: I do agree it feels a little bouncier than in ME2, though.

Comment: I think I may be a bit trigger happy because of ME2's lack of sway, maybe I just need to slow it down a little here.

Comment: @DeanMc - I would recommend slowing down and focusing on headshots.  You can put out a lot of pain with just a few pulls of the trigger, here.

Comment: Also, another way to significantly improve the muzzle climb and accuracy is to fire from cover always.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that a lvl 5 Stability Damper does wonders. It doesn't matter how accurate your gun is or how much damage it does if you can't aim straight. IMO it's worth it to spend one slot for a damper mod.

Answer (score 2):

An un-upgraded mattock is a beast that I initially had no interest in, but once I upgraded it to level 5 and fitted it with a recoil dampener (level 2 I believe), it barely kicked at all.

In the spectre shooting range on the citadel, I was able to set the targets to medium distance and put 5 shots into the head without any pause, and with no visible lift in the crosshairs. And that's without firing from cover.

Answer (score 0):

I just compensate for its kick - it's not too unwieldy. In fact, you can use it up close and just unload the whole clip onto an enemy. It usually takes them down, even Centurions on normal (in insanity, this is an insane tactic). If you treat it like a DMR (designated marksmen rifle from HALO), then you can easily get the grips of the weapon.

I personally liked using a scope and penetration shot mods on it, since you can use it almost like a sniper rifle with a high rate of fire.